# VirtualBox only creates new virtual hard disk when there is enough space on 'C' drive

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

There are >200GB free on my 'F' drive but it failed to create a fixed-size VHD with size = 200GB.

> Failed to create the hard disk storage C:\Users\abc\VirtualBox
>   VMs\OSOS\OSOS.vhd.
>
> Could not create the medium storage unit 'C:\Users\abc\VirtualBox
>   VMs\OSOS\OSOS.vhd'.
>
> VHD: cannot set the file size for 'C:\Users\abc\VirtualBox
>   VMs\OSOS\OSOS.vhd' (VERR_DISK_FULL).

I can only create a VHD with size as much as the amount free on the 'C' drive.
Is there away to make VirtualBox recognizes that there is free space on other drives?

Comment: If you want to use free space from drive `F:`, then you should create your `VHD` on drive `F:`, not `C:`.

Comment: VirtualBox Does not support spanning the .vhd across multiple storage locations.  It sounds like you should move the file to the storage drive with additional storage capacity.